# How to handle background notifications in iOS with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications in my iOS app. And it works fine.

However, in my app, the users can log in and log out. So I need to make sure the users won't receive notifications while logged out.

I can check if the user is logged in in my app delegate while app is running. Here is how I do this in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application( application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

    if defaults.stringForKey("authKey") != nil{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        showNotification(userInfo)
    }
}
```

However, when app is not running, my methods in app delegate to check if user is logged in do not work. And I don't know where to make this check while app is not running. Which methods are used to show notifications while app is in background?

[Here is all of my AppDelegate](https://gist.github.com/yigitserin/9c93d137d406b11b967394e8aaeee651)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle application delegate

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

Look at the details blog related to [remote notification in background mode](http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/)